# C++ iterator equality

Tags: c++, design-patterns, std

How does c++ std library implement for example, vector iterators? It allows you to do equality testing on a regular iterator and a reverse iterator, what kind of design allows this to be possible?

Edit: So below someone responded with the actual code of overloaded == method, which is not what i'm looking for, so maybe the scope of this question wasn't clear. What I mean by "how does the std library implement vector iterators" is more of a design level question of what kind of inheritance tree does the iterator class use, what were some design trade-offs with doing it that way, other alternative designs, etc. If someone could shed some light on this that would be great.

Comment: A vector iterator probably just wraps a pointer. Two vector iterators are equal, then, if they point to the same thing.

Comment: But don't ignore the fact that there are many implementations of the standard library. One day you may run across one implemented by a raving lunatic or absolute genius (sometimes the same thing, but not always) who meets the standard while doing something utterly bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

This is from `<vector>`:

```
bool operator==(const _Myiter& _Right) const
    {   // test for iterator equality
        _Compat(_Right);
         return (this->_Ptr == _Right._Ptr);
    }
```

The iterator contains a pointer `_Ptr` as a member. This is typical of all iterators. They are wrappers to a reference into the collection.

Comment: I'm looking for a more design oriented answer, you can see the details of what i'm looking for in the edit.